# How to hide a list item according to its html content?

Tags: javascript, html, list, function, hide

```
<div class="icon-list-item">
  <span class="icon-list-text">One</span>
</div>
<div class="icon-list-item">
  <span class="icon-list-text">Two</span>
</div>
<div class="icon-list-item">
  <span class="icon-list-text">Three</span>
</div>
<div class="icon-list-item">
  <span class="icon-list-text">empty</span>
</div>
```

I would like to hide/remove any div that contains a span with "empty" content

I have tried many functions but none of them worked. Can you help me find some JS that can solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Explanation** : The `forEach` iterates through all the `div` elements having class `icon-list-item`. The `spanChild` variable holds the child element of the div element of current iteration. `remove()` function is used to remove element from DOM, when the text inside `spanChild` is *"empty"*.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-list-item');

divs.forEach((el) => {
  let spanChild = el.children[0];
  if(spanChild.innerText.trim() === "empty")
    el.remove(); 
});
```

```html
<div class="icon-list-item">
  <span class="icon-list-text">One</span>
</div>
<div class="icon-list-item">
  <span class="icon-list-text">Two</span>
</div>
<div class="icon-list-item">
  <span class="icon-list-text">Three</span>
</div>
<div class="icon-list-item">
  <span class="icon-list-text">empty</span>
</div>
```